# How to change settings for a specific player in Photon?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm making a simple Word Builder type of game (where one player enters a word, and the other player enters a word starting with the last letter of the first player's word), and I'm trying to get it so that the MasterClient starts the the game by typing in the first word, then his InputField gets disabled, and the second player's InputField gets enabled, and he types a word and vice versa.

I have tried multiple ways, all of which were from my basic knowledge of Unity and C#. Here's one for example that I thought would definitely work, but didn't.

```
    public void ChangeTurn ()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            inputField.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            inputField.enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

To put in in short, is there a way to do something like, `PhotonNetwork.PlayerList[0].inputField.enabled = false;`? Please tell me if there's a way I can solve this? I will be eternally grateful.

Comment: this might give you some direction, [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/677213/photon-fps-disableenable-objects-over-network.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the currently active [`Player.ActorNumber`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_player.html#ae336775e717f1f825f2955fc8b627738) and on the Master use [`Player.GetNextFor`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_realtime_1_1_player.html#a2ed670bab5620846d104dc24588526e9)

> Gets a Player's next Player, as sorted by ActorNumber (Player.ID). Wraps around.
>
> Useful when you pass something to the next player. For example: passing the turn to the next player.

like e.g.

```
private int currentID;

...
    currentID = Player.GetNextFor(currentID).ActorNumber;
...
```

And then transmit it to everyone e.g. via an [`RPC`](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent)

```
...
    photonView.RPC(nameof(ChangeTurn), RpcTarget.All, currentID);
...

// This will be executed on all clients
[PunRPC]
private void ChangeTurn(int newID)
{
    // Simply check if the given newID matches your own ActorNumber
    inputField.enabled = PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber == newID;
}
```

So all together e.g. something like

```
// Store the ID of the currently active player
private int currentID;

// This is what a client has to call when he is done with his turn
private void EndTurn()
{
    // Tell only the masterClient that we are done
    // and he shall change the turn to the next player
   photonView.RPC(nameof(ChangeTurnOnMaster), RpcTarget.MasterClient);
}

// This will be executed on the MasterClient
[PunRPC]
private void ChangeTurnOnMaster()
{
    // Just to be really sure this is only done on the master client
    if(!PhotoNetwork.isMasterClient) return;

    // Get the next actor number
    // This wraps around so after reaching the last player it will again start with the first one
    currentID = Player.GetNextFor(currentID).ActorNumber;

    // Tell everyone the new active player ID
    photonView.RPC(nameof(ChangeTurn), RpcTarget.All, currentID);
}

// This will be executed on all clients
[PunRPC]
private void ChangeTurn(int newID)
{
    // Just in case let everyone store the active ID
    // this way you can also handle other things based on the ID later
    // And also deal with the case that the masterClient switches for some reason
    currentID = newID;

    // Simply check if the given newID matches your own ActorNumber
    inputField.enabled = PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber == newID;
}
```

Comment: I've been trying for a couple of hours now, and I can't seem to get it to work, can you please elaborate in another answer?

Comment: @JamalH.A added some comments and a more complete example code .. hope it is clearer now ;)

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! You have literally taught me so much just by replying to my posts in the last few days.
Also, https://imgur.com/a/cPJcG6O